# css: Use single-sided outline and outline-offset?

Tags: html, css, image, border

I would like to put an internal frame to an image with `outline` and `outline-offset` but only on the top and bottom, however there is no such thing as `outline-offset-top`, `outline-offset-bottom`, `outline-offset-left` or `outline-offset-right`.

Does anyone know of any way or alternative to do this?

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
    outline: 70px solid white;     
    outline-offset: -70px;
}
```

```html
    <img src="https://cdnnmundo1.img.sputniknews.com/img/07e5/08/17/1115327694_182:0:2230:2048_1920x0_80_0_0_0642590b6896368f2c051719f7c66ea7.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

use clip-path to cut the top part instead of adding a white color

```css
img {
  clip-path:inset(70px 0 0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cr.epaenlinea.com/pub/media/version20200605/catalog/product/cache/a83b746ef25730b9cb1cc414bac0f04a/1/2/1246118_3.jpg">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, any way to put a background to the disappearing area?